How to safely allow an untrusted PC to a network share?
I have a Windows 10 PC which serves as the controller of a laser cutting machine.  The PC has updates turned off to ensure that nothing ever changes that could cause a future issue or incompatibility with the machine that it is dedicated to.
Since it will not receive windows updates, I therefore do not trust this PC and want to keep it isolated from the rest of my network.
However, it needs to have access to one network share (on a NAS) so it can access its laser cutting programs and related files.
I already have the PC on its own subnet and vlan which is isolated from the rest of the network, and which does not have internet access.  But giving it access to the network shared drive of gives it access to this important shared resource.
What are the best practices for allowing access to a shared drive, by an untrusted PC like this?

Why are the program and related files on a network file share and not on the [isolated] machine itself?  If they have to be on a separate machine, can they be moved to a server that is similarly-isolated to the machine itself (i.e. two machines on their own little sub-network)?

When I refer to "programs" which need to be on the network share, I am referring to code that contains the cutting paths for the laser cutter to follow.  We keep these on a network share because we regularly make new cutting programs on other computers, which need to be transferred over.  Sorry for the confusion, since a "program" can also refer to an application which would normally be resident on the isolated PC.


What are the best practices for allowing access to a shared drive, by an untrusted PC like this?

Put the files needed in a folder that has a separate, dedicated share.

If you want to only read (download) those files from the computer connected to the laser cutting machine, create an HTTP share, using for example Apatche, and make that share password protected, if needed
